# How to trigger a workflow in Azure Logic App along with parameters taken by trigger as input?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflowtriggers/run

The above REST API has no option to pass trigger parameters in body, even though it is a "POST" call.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You can pass it as Headers and receive those values using the `Header` object

Comment: I tried passing both 'Name' and 'body = {'Name':"foo"}' as headers, but both didn't work. Should they be passed in some other way?

Comment: Can you post the run details ? and what is the connector that you are using >

Comment: Solvedt the problem. I discovered that the REST API i mentioned above in question does accept the input in body. Its only that the "try it" feature in API documentation was not showing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want your HTTP endpoint URL to accept parameters, customize your trigger's relative path.

First on your `Request` trigger, choose `Show advanced options`. Under `Relative path`, specify the relative path for the parameter that your URL should accept, for example, name/{name}.

[image]

To use the parameter, add a `Response` action to your logic app.

In your response's Body, include the token for the parameter that you specified in your trigger's relative path.For example, to return `Hello {name}`, update your response's Body with `Hello {name}`.

[image]

Then you could add it into `Body` when you post a call.

[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint#accept-parameters-through-your-http-endpoint-url).

**Update**:

The REST API mentioned above in question does accept the input in body. Its only that the "try it" feature in API documentation was not showing it.

Comment: In my case, I cannot edit the user's workflow. I can only fetch the trigger schema and then let the user provide inputs according to schema. I discovered that the REST API i mentioned above in question does accept the input in body. Its only that the "try it" feature in API documentation was not showing it.